# Encoding issue when post php javascript AJAX

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, encoding, utf-8

I have an issue that bothers me for two days already.
When I send datas with jQuery ajax, the php file encodes it wrong. 
Here is the ajax code:

```
function valideffective(ecole)
{
    'validationecole.php',
    {
        type: "validation",
        name: $(ecole).parent().children("td").eq(0).html(),
        city:$(ecole).parent().children("td").eq(1).html()
    },
    function(data)
    {
        $(ecole).parent().toggle(500);
    },
    'text'
);
}
```

PHP code:

```
$so = $request->Validation ( $_POST ["name"], $_POST ["city"] );
if ($so == 1) 
{
    echo "OK";
} 
else 
{
    echo $_POST ["name"];
}
```

When I echo what the php file gets, all the accent (é,à,è,...) are like Ã©...
I checked the headers, they are all utf-8.. I dont know how to fix this problem

Comment: So, the "PHP sends it wrong", but you don't post your PHP code?

Comment: I changed the post but its just a simple echo of what i sent with ajax

Comment: Looks like you need to change the header. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4064444/returning-json-from-a-php-script

Comment: Also, not sure what your javascript is supposed to do... You have an extra bracket in there also.